# Jquery: How can I set a modal dialog to display centered relative to html instead of body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, positioning

I'm using a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248054/jquery-how-do-i-trigger-a-modal-window-just-from-the-existence-of-an-element) that greys out the background with a `#mask` element and centers my `.memError` message on the screen. The problem is that my site styles both the `body` and the `html` elements-- `body` is fixed-width and centered within the `html` element. When I use the script below, the `#mask` and `.memError` message are both positioned relative to the `body` element. How can I position them relative to `html` instead?

```
//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({
    'width': maskWidth,
    'height': maskHeight
});

//transition effect
$('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
$('#mask').fadeTo("normal", 0.9);

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$('.memError').css('top', winH / 2 - $('.memError').height() / 2);
$('.memError').css('left', winW / 2 - $('.memError').width() / 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you set top & left position to zero?

```
$('#mask').css({
 'width': maskWidth,
 'height': maskHeight,
 'left': 0,
 'top': 0
});
```

but, why don't you give [blockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) a try?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use jmodal or another jquery plugin that builds a modal dialog for you?